# Magento 2.4.6-p4 upgrade results in 503 Error

Tags: magento-upgrade

I've been struggling to upgrade a store from Magento CE 2.4.3 to the more recent version and I approached it by doing it in stages. I currently have a working 2.4.5-p6 store but if I move to 2.4.6-p4 I get

`Error 503 Backend fetch failed
Backend fetch failed

Guru Meditation:
XID: 32852

Varnish cache server`

The upgrade happened without incident with the exception that I got a PHP fatal error related to the count function in vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php and a count function vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Repository/CompositeRepository.php -- both of which I fixed manually and then the upgrade proceeded.

Does anyone have any insight into what would be the issue, what I should be looking at next, or even better how I fix this?

The store has no extensions, no custom code, and is using the default theme. This is just a basic store built on 2.4.3 that I am upgrading because it was recently attacked which motivated me to move to the most recent version of Magento.

I have tried it with both PHP 8.1 and 8.2. Varnish returns a version number of 6.4

Answer (score 0):

Please go to **`\vendor\composer\composer\src\Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository.php`**

Change **`public function count()`** to **`public function count(): int`**

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but that is not the issue. 

To upgrade to 2.4.6-p4 I was getting a PHP fatal error because of ArrayRepository.php and CompoisteRepository.php in both cases because of the missing int which I manually added so that change has already been made. 

To confirm I checked ArrayRepository.php to ensure that the edits I previously made were still there and they are.

Any additional suggestions would be appreciated.